# How to use regex with replace in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a csv file with fields in format given below ...

```
ram(tower)america
shyam(t.nagar)japan
john(jam nagar)netherland
```

i want to change this in format given below

```
ram","america
shyam","japan
john","netherland
```

How can i do this in Notepad++ with regex

Comment: you should have shown what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Open 'Find and Replace' dialogue box with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in Notepad++. Write the following:

- Find what: `\(.+?\)`
- Replace with: `","`

#### Syntax used:

- Backward slash and left brace: Find left brace
- Single dot and plus sign: Matches any character
- Backward slash and right brace: Find right brace

[image: Notepad++_Find_and_Replace]

### Further reading:

- [How to find, replace and highlight text in Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Searching_And_Replacing)
- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

In the Notepad++ find/replace dialogue:

- Find what: `(.*?)\(.*\)(.*)`
- Replace with: `$1","$2`

Here is the screenshot of Notepad++ find/replace dialogue window:

[image: Notepad++ find/replace dialogue window screenshot]